# gpg creation but no progress bar

Tags: 14.04, gnupg

Is there no longer a progress bar or some indecator when you create a gpg key in the passwords and keys app? I wasnt sure it was doing anything until later my new keys were there. Should this be reported as a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried throwing this flag at it?

```
--enable-progress-filter
```